# Does Oracle allow an SQL INSERT INTO using a SELECT statement for VALUES if the destination table has an GENERATE ALWAYS AS IDENTITY COLUMN

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, identity

I am trying to insert rows into an Oracle 19c table that we recently added a GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY column (column name is "ID").  The column should auto-increment and not need to be specified explicitly in an INSERT statement.  Typical INSERT statements work - i.e. INSERT INTO table_name (field1,field2) VALUES ('f1', 'f2'). (merely an example).  The ID field increments when typical INSERT is executed.   But the query below, that was working before the addition of the IDENTITY COLUMN, is now not working and returning the error:  ORA-00947: not enough values.

The field counts are identical with the exception of not including the new ID IDENTITY field, which I am expecting to auto-increment. Is this statement not allowed with an IDENTITY column?

Is the INSERT INTO statement, using a SELECT from another table, not allowing this and producing the error?

```
INSERT INTO T.AUDIT
(SELECT r.IDENTIFIER, r.SERIAL, r.NODE, r.NODEALIAS, r.MANAGER, r.AGENT, r.ALERTGROUP,
r.ALERTKEY, r.SEVERITY, r.SUMMARY, r.LASTMODIFIED, r.FIRSTOCCURRENCE, r.LASTOCCURRENCE,
r.POLL, r.TYPE, r.TALLY, r.CLASS, r.LOCATION, r.OWNERUID, r.OWNERGID, r.ACKNOWLEDGED,
r.EVENTID, r.DELETEDAT, r.ORIGINALSEVERITY, r.CATEGORY, r.SITEID, r.SITENAME, r.DURATION,
r.ACTIVECLEARCHANGE, r.NETWORK, r.EXTENDEDATTR, r.SERVERNAME, r.SERVERSERIAL, r.PROBESUBSECONDID
FROM R.STATUS r
JOIN
(SELECT SERVERSERIAL, MAX(LASTOCCURRENCE) as maxlast
FROM T.AUDIT
GROUP BY SERVERSERIAL) gla
ON r.SERVERSERIAL = gla.SERVERSERIAL
WHERE (r.LASTOCCURRENCE > SYSDATE - (1/1440)*5 AND gla.maxlast < r.LASTOCCURRENCE)
) )
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to specify the target columns `insert into audit (c1, c2, c3, ...)`

Comment: i specified the target columns and the script is now working. thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does; your example insert

```
INSERT INTO table_name (field1,field2) VALUES ('f1', 'f2')
```

would also work as

```
INSERT INTO table_name (field1,field2) SELECT 'f1', 'f2' FROM DUAL
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=924dc795f5cf8f5fbd830ee5839fee56)

Your problematic real insert statement is not specifying the target column list, so when it used to work it was relying on the columns in the table (and their data types) matching the results of the query. (This is similar to relying on `select *`, and potentially problematic for some of the same reasons.)

Your query selects 34 values, so your table had 34 columns. You have now added a 35th column to the table, your new ID column. You know that you don't want to insert directly into that column, but in general Oracle doesn't, at least at the point it's comparing the query with the table columns. The table has 35 columns, so as you haven't said otherwise as part of the statement, it is expecting 35 values in the select list.

There's no way for Oracle to know which of the 35 columns you're skipping. Arguably it could guess based on the identity column, but that would be more work and inconsistent, and it's not unreasonable for it to insist you do the work to make sure it's right. It's expecting 35 values, it sees 34, so it throws an error saying there are not enough values - which is true.

Your question sort of implies you think Oracle might be doing something special to prevent the `insert ... select ...` syntax if there is an identity column, but in facts it's the opposite - it *isn't* doing anything special, and it's reporting the column/value count mismatch as it usually would.

So, you have to list the columns you are populating - you can't automatically skip one. So you statement needs to be:

```
INSERT INTO T.AUDIT (IDENTIFIER, SERIAL, NODE, ...,  PROBESUBSECONDID)
SELECT r.IDENTIFIER, r.SERIAL, r.NODE, ...,  r.PROBESUBSECONDID
FROM ...
```

using the actual column names of course if they differ from the query column names.

---

If you can't change that insert statement then you *could* make the ID column invisible; but then you would have to specify it explicitly in queries, as `select *` won't see it - but then you shouldn't rely on `*` anyway.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c0b570b244e12b5c2f61e56229efdd55)

Comment: i specified the target columns and the script is now working.  thanks.